# My news script wont organize news by the right order

Tags: php

So, basicly theres a problem with reading the dates and ordering them by the right order.
I'm not sure why, but it sometimes show the date of today.
Can anyone of you fellas clean the code? I believe it's too messy, i'm not that good with php.

Basicly, the news script works like this:
it reads from includes/news folder which has .txt files of news.
each news file has a name like this: `[09.12.2013] random news title`,
and it needs to be ordered from latest to oldest, (newest up, oldest goes down), i.e. in reverse chronological order.

Appreciate any effort to help here, thanks.

```
<?
$files = array();
if($handle = opendir( 'includes/news' )) {
    while( $file = readdir( $handle )) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
            // let's check for txt extension
            $extension = substr($file, -3);
            // filename without '.txt'
            $filename = substr($file, 0, -4);
            if ($extension == 'txt')
                $files[] = $filename; // or $filename
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
rsort($files);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    // get post date
    $postdate = substr($file, 0, 10);
    $postdate = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $postdate);
    $todaysdate = date("d.m.y");
    if($postdate == $todaysdate) { $fromtoday = "true"; }
    $postdate = date('F jS, Y', strtotime($postdate));
    $filetitle  = substr($file, 10);
    if($fromtoday == "true") { echo "<b style=\"color: #ffb400;\">&#8987; NEW:</b>"; }
    echo '<a href="?module=news&read=' . $file . '"><span style="float:right;">' . $postdate . '</span>' . $filetitle . "</a>";
}

?>
```

Comment: [09.12.2013] is pretty stupid for ordering, why not  [2013.09.12] ?

Comment: abit confusing, to be honest. but i think i can do it. question is, is my code clean enough?

Comment: also, it gets mixed sometimes.. are you sure its the solution for the ordering?

Comment: Agree with @MightyPork should be ordered by Ymd..

Comment: You also format $todaysdate with small "y" so it gives only two digit year number.. use capital Y instead to get four digit number..

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to use [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
bool usort ( array &$array , callable $value_compare_func )
```

You will have to make a function for the comparison (`$value_compare_func`) that will parse the dates from the strings, and compare them. It's best to see the documentation for examples.

You'd use it like this:

```
usort($files, function($a, $b) {
        // here is the comparison logic
        // return -1,0 or 1
});
```

This way you can sort by dates you parse with regex from the string (or anything else).

To achieve the reverse order, just swap -1 and 1 in the sort function.